# Displaying the child data under parent data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, eloquent

I have two tables which is `behavioralmain` and `behavioralsub` the behavioralsub is the chils table of the behavioralmain. Apparently, the behavioralsub have parent_id which is corresponding to the id of the behavioralmain. I've tried to join the two table with the use of this code.
`behavioralmain Table`

```
ID |   category_name  |   actual weight   | weight
 1      commitment            0               7
 2      category              0               5
```

`behavioralsub Table`

```
ID |   category_name  |   parent_id   |  weight
 1      administer            1            7
 2      president             1            5
 3      secretary             2            7
 4      mixture               2            5
```

`behavioralmain.model`

```
     /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $table = 'behavioralmain';


    public function behavioralsub()
         {
            return $this->hasMany('BehavioralSub','id','parent_id');
         }

}
```

`behavoiralsub.model`

```
<?php 
class BehavioralSub  extends Eloquent   {

     /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $table = 'behavioralsub';

    protected $fillable=array('id','survey_question','weight');


    public function parenting() {
    return $this->belongsTo('behavioralmain','id','parent_id');
  }
}
```

`BehavoiralSubController.php`

```
public function index()
    {
        return View::make('behavioralsub.index')->with('sub',BehavioralSub::get())->with('sub',BehavioralMcain::with(array('behavioralsub'))->get());
    }
```

`Index.blade.php`

```
 <tbody>
@foreach($sub as $sub)
    <tr>
      <td>{{{$sub->category_name}}}</td>
      <td>{{{$sub->survey_question}}}</td>
      <td>{{{$sub->weight}}}</td>                    
      <td><a href="{{{route('behavioralsub.edit',$sub->id)}}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>                        
      </td>
      <td>
                                        <a href="{{{route('behavioralsub.destroy',$sub->id)}}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>                        

                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
```

In the code above, I assume that it can get what I want but sad to say the only displays in the view side is this only;this the parent table while the child table didn't retrieve,
`category`,`commitment`.

The output that I need is like this.

```
commitment
   -administer
   -president
category
   -secretary
   -mixture
```

Please how to do this. I've tried everything but nothing's happen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

behavioralsub model:

```
public function parenting() {
    return $this->belongsTo('BehavioralMain', 'parent_id', 'ID');
}
```

behavioralmain model

```
public function behavioralsub() {
    return $this->hasMany('BehavioralSub', 'parent_id', 'ID');
}
```

The way you are passing data to the View has closing parenthesis in all the wrong places and seems to be method chaining the wrong objects. Try changing it to:

```
public function index() {
        return View::make('behavioralsub.index')->with(array('main' => BehavioralMcain::with('behavioralsub')->get());
}
```

which would make your view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($main->behavioralsub as $sub)
        <tr>
            <td>{{{$sub->category_name}}}</td>
            <td>{{{$sub->survey_question}}}</td>
            <td>{{{$sub->weight}}}</td>                    
            <td>
                <a href="{{{route('behavioralsub.edit',$sub->id)}}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>                        
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{{route('behavioralsub.destroy',$sub->id)}}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>                        

            </td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Still the same output. No changes happens :(

Comment: Still the same.. I don't know what's wrong about the code.

Comment: Please I need your help. I'm freaking out here. I can't anything to solve my problem